# <a4j:ajax oncomplete> is not triggered while <a4j:support oncomplete> did

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm trying to trigger a javascript function using the a4j:ajax method. We are migrating from version 3 to version 4, and have also been upgrading spring and JSF. Previously, this worked fine:

```
<a4j:support event="change" oncomplete="callJavascriptMethod()">
```

With version 4 of RichFaces, I'm trying to do the same, calling a javascript function everytime a dropdown list is beeing changed, but I have changed to use:

```
<a4j:ajax event="change" oncomplete="callJavascriptMethod()">
```

I have also tried something like this just to see if the event's are triggered:

```
<h:commandButton id="test" value="Test me!">
    <a4j:ajax event="click" oncomplete="console.log('something');" />
</h:commandButton>
```

So far without luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what RichFaces is doing here, but why don't you just use `<a4j:commandButton>` instead of `<h:commandButton><a4j:ajax>`?

Comment: The commandButton example was just to check if oncomplete would work there. I'm not actually using that in my code. The a4j:ajax part is inside a custom codes table selector. It was to verify that I have the same issue in a simpler example.

Comment: Okay. Did you check browser's JS console and HTTP traffic monitor for clues? It's quite possible that you forgot to migrate `<head>` to `<h:head>` and therefore RichFaces wasn't able to auto-include the necessary JS library.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still using <h:head>, and I cant find much information in the js console or networking tab. I also tested with a4j:commandButton, and there it works fine if I try to trigger the javascript function from the onclick-method. It's only oncomplete that doesn't work.

Comment: @EspenS. - have you verified this behaviour across multiple browsers?

Comment: IE and Chrome so far.

Answer (score 1):

The commandButton example above is working in our migration. We had a lot of issues with a4j:ajax in 4.3.2 but upgrading to 4.3.4 seemed to fix most of the issues, so if that is an option and hasn't been done I would recommend getting the latest version for RichFaces 4.